# VBA - MS Project - Add space to duration field

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am receiving different project files that all need to be formatted the same. The duration field is formatted in one of them to contain no space ("50d"). I need all the project files to have a space in the duration field so they read "50 d".

I've searched but can't seem to find the method that allows me to edit this. Does anyone know the right method to adjust this?

Application.DurationFormat seemed close but I did not see any option in the PjFormatUnit for the duration in days with space.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. Corrected it now.
I need to add a space. I'm sure either way the formatting option should be fairly similar whether its adding/removing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is [SpaceBeforeTimeLabels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.spacebeforetimelabels) and you can set it to True or False as needed. It is a project-level property, for example:

```
ActiveProject.SpaceBeforeTimeLabels = True
```

Related: [DayLabelDisplay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.daylabeldisplay), [HourLabelDisplay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.hourlabeldisplay), [MinuteLabelDisplay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.minutelabeldisplay), [WeekLabelDisplay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.weeklabeldisplay), [YearLabelDisplay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.yearlabeldisplay)

For example, use DayLabelDisplay to show "50 d" vs "50 days".

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!